# How to do an order by ACROSS multiple columns

Tags: sql, join, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, sql-order-by

I need to do an order by across multiple columns.

I am using Spring data jpa for my queries.

e.g Consider the following dataset :

```
id | name     | scientific_name
---------------------------
1  | Rose     |
2  |          | Canna generalis
3  |          | Dianthus chinensis
4  | Hibiscus |
5  |          | Helianthus
6  | Daisy    |
```

While ordering, I want to perform order on name and scientific_name at same time.

NOT like order by name and then order by scientific_name.

Desired result after order by :

```
id | name     | scientific_name
---------------------------
2  |          | Canna generalis
6  | Daisy    |
3  |          | Dianthus chinensis
5  |          | Helianthus
4  | Hibiscus |
1  | Rose     |
```

Comment: You need to give us the logic for how to achieve this ordering, which your current table does not seem to possess.

Comment: What dbms are you using ?

Comment: I want to sort the records in name and scientific_name by ascending order. Thats it !!! But simultaneously

Comment: I am using postgres database

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to look for is

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(name, scientific_name)
```

you can use it in a JPQL statement provided in a `@Query` annotation and it also should work in a native query since it is standard SQL and supported by many databases.

If your "empty" columns don't contain `null` but empty strings instead you can handle that with:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(name, ''), scientific_name)
```

Comment: COALESCE is not ordering the columns simultaneously. I have tried your example, but it is not returning the expected result. Instead it is sorting first by scientific_name and then by name.
```
 id |   name   |    scientific_name        
----+----------+--------------------
  2 |          | Canna generalis
  3 |          | Dianthus chinensis
  5 |          | Helianthus
  6 | Daisy    | 
  4 | Hibiscus | 
  1 | Rose     |
```

Comment: It is working if I have nulls, I had specified blank instead of null.
If I have non null values (blank) then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query. `order by` will do this trick

```
select t1.* from testA t1
left join testA t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
order by isnull(t2.scientific_name, t1.[name]) asc
```

Comment: It is giving almost same results as coalesce function. 
It is not sorting and ordering it simultaneously.
Instead it is sorting first by name and then by scientific_name.